# PHP: how to make startup warnings fatal?

Tags: php, preload

I try to make a verification process for my PHP preloading script.

In order to ensure that I don't have un-managed classes I'm running a script in CLI like:

```sh
     php \
        -d error_reporting=2147483647 \
        -d opcache.enable_cli=1 \
        -d display_errors=1 \
        -d display_startup_errors=1 \
        -d memory_limit=96M \
        -d opcache.preload=preload.php \
         tools/utils/preload/check-preload.php
```

I'm getting a warning because one of the class cannot be complied du to missing dependencies. E.g.:

```
Warning: Can't preload unlinked class User\Profile\ForceRegenerationDefaultAvatarCommand: Unknown parent Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command in /home/mvacelet/workspace/tuleap/src/common/User/Profile/ForceRegenerationDefaultAvatarCommand.php on line 32
```

That's great but the issue I have is that I cannot make this warning fatal. More specifically I would like `check-preload.php` script to exit with status code different of 0 so my CI can fail.

I cannot find a relevant configuration setting and custom error_handler will not work with startup errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the information I was missing is that the custom error handler must be in the **preload** file.

As this was mainly for dev/CI purpose to be sure the preload generated by new development will not generate warnings, I went a little bit more subtle:

I now have a `verify-preload.php` file that does:

```php
    set_error_handler(static fn ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) => die("$errstr $errfile L$errline\n"), E_ALL);

    require __DIR__ . '/preload.php';
```

and my verification call is:

```sh
     php \
        -d error_reporting=2147483647 \
        -d opcache.enable_cli=1 \
        -d display_errors=1 \
        -d display_startup_errors=1 \
        -d memory_limit=96M \
        -d opcache.preload=verify-preload.php \
         tools/utils/preload/check-preload.php
```

This way:

- During development or CI, I rely on `verify-preload.php` so errors are caught.
- In production, I don't take the risk of making fatal an harmless warning (remember in this context, warnings are mainly informative that given file will not be preloaded, it doesn't have any impact on production).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own Error/Exception handling. First you need to set the error-reporting level with:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL);
```

then you can implement two simple methods to handle all occuring Errors/Exceptions. The method for Errors looks like this:

```
function handle_error ($number, $message, $file, $line, $context = null) {

    //change error to exception
    throw new ErrorException ($message, 0, $number, $file, $line);

}
```

For exception-handling the method looks like:

```
function handle_exception (Throwable $exception) {

    //here you can check for warnings
    var_dump ($exception)

}
```

Now you just need to register those methods with:

```
set_error_handler ('handle_error');

set_exception_handler ('handle_exception');
```